# Weblogic 10.3.1 version not showing JNDI tree stucture

Tags: server, jndi, naming, weblogic-10.x, weblogic11g

I have created Admin server and followed these steps as per docs:

To view objects in the JNDI tree:
In the left pane expand Environment > Servers.
On the Server summary page click the name of the server, for example, myserver.
On the server Settings page click View JNDI Tree.
The JNDI tree is displayed in a new window.

But its throwing class not found exception and not showing anything .
Same is working in 10.3.6 version.
Anyone knows how to fix this issue in 10.3.1 version ?

Comment: Please share the complete stack trace when exception is raised by the console

Comment: I have resolved this issue by adding listen address as localhost in config.xml